# solidity_keccak not matching JS keccak256(abi.encodePacked(

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python

I'm trying to reproduce a signature that a contract verifies but I'm unable to do it on web3py. To verify I'm producing a signature correctly I'm going to look at an already produced signature and verify that the address is correct. First here's my code:

```
hash = Web3.solidity_keccak(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'], ["0xf7FA3C8C9Ba3FfCFA1d5f0ca5C9294Afd5970aE7", 1, 59144, 1])
message = defunct_hash_message(hash)
address = w3.eth.account._recover_hash(message, signature=HexBytes("0x599f3172abf3bf5029ee5ea53b5119fa2c9d5de3fa434fd81d46209fb0ab1d230a6c5a0946b59942f94e1b352d325db1bf938a608eb13cbc89ce7184e2d6112b1c"))
print(address)
```

The output is `0x784aD8676Ade4DEE288fd3f36e2F2EbDfdF70765` but should be `0xf7FA3C8C9Ba3FfCFA1d5f0ca5C9294Afd5970aE7`

[This](https://lineascan.build/address/0xc577018b3518cd7763d143d7699b280d6e50fdb6) is the contract and specifically, I'm looking at `newTicket` function. Specifically if you look at the code [here](https://lineascan.build/address/0xc577018b3518cd7763d143d7699b280d6e50fdb6#code), `LotteryMaster.sol#126`you can see this is being done in solidity:

```
keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(to, txHashes.length, block.chainid, sessionIdx))
        );  // include session index so the signature only affect only for this session
        require(isValidSignature(toAddressHash, _signature), "Mismatch signature.");
```

If you look at this successful transaction [here](https://lineascan.build/tx/0x1b2db08c7f609a92c6ab509713801feaaad8ecfad339a008be1593a697e1ed8f)  it has the full signature. Now I want to be able to recover the address like they do in the code. But for that I need to hash the message correctly. If you look at their code you can determine the message parameters by looking at the transaction itself, and so should be able to create the hash that would return the address using the signature. But I can't seem to do that. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Another example using an open private key:
Take a look at this [TX](https://lineascan.build/tx/0xef1940323fa4ac34dd1cb12a5462269ec3cfceae0c9820eab2bc05afb6fc5fb4). The code if you go according to the example would be:

```
private_key = b"\xb2\\}\xb3\x1f\xee\xd9\x12''\xbf\t9\xdcv\x9a\x96VK-\xe4\xc4rm\x03[6\xec\xf1\xe5\xb3d"
wallet_address = '0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E'
_hash = w3.keccak(encode_packed(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256'], [wallet_address, 113, 200]))
signer = w3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)
signed = signer.signHash(_hash.hex())
print(signed)

r = requests.post('https://ape.ankr.com/api/v2/linea/getSign', json={'address': wallet_address, 'boxId': 113, 'continue': True}).json()
print(r['data']['sign'])
```

The above two don't match. The latter api is just a helper function that produces the same signature that is verified on the smart contract. As you can see I don't pass a private key, so the API can't sign it, but it is verified on the smart contract. I'm confused as to how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it is `toEthSignedMessageHash` are you encoding the message before signing?

From the contract you link:

```js
  function toEthSignedMessageHash(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32 message) {
    // 32 is the length in bytes of hash,
    // enforced by the type signature above
    /// @solidity memory-safe-assembly
    assembly {
      mstore(0x00, "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32")
      mstore(0x1c, hash)
      message := keccak256(0x00, 0x3c)
    }
  }
```

If I use the key from the example here:

- https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-message

```py
>>> private_key = b"\xb2\\}\xb3\x1f\xee\xd9\x12''\xbf\t9\xdcv\x9a\x96VK-\xe4\xc4rm\x03[6\xec\xf1\xe5\xb3d"
>>> w3.eth.account.from_key(private_key).address
'0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E'
>>>
>>> _hash = w3.keccak(encode_packed(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'], ["0xf7FA3C8C9Ba3FfCFA1d5f0ca5C9294Afd5970aE7", 1, 59144, 1])) #same as solidity_keccak
>>> encoded_msg = encode_defunct(hexstr=_hash.hex())
>>>
>>> encoded_msg
SignableMessage(version=b'E', header=b'thereum Signed Message:\n32', body=b"@\xedDx\x1bI\xa8\\U\x04\xe7\r4\xd8\xe4\xf7\xda@y;\x82\xb5mA'\x82\xf5\xf8\x06\x87I\x18")
>>> signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(encoded_msg, private_key=private_key)
>>>
>>> w3.eth.account.recover_message(encoded_msg, signature=signed_message.signature)
'0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E'
```

---

**edit:**

Please try like this (it's as with the xSwap example I posted below):

```
>>> private_key = b"\xb2\\}\xb3\x1f\xee\xd9\x12''\xbf\t9\xdcv\x9a\x96VK-\xe4\xc4rm\x03[6\xec\xf1\xe5\xb3d"
>>> _hash = w3.keccak(encode_packed(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'], ["0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E", 1, 59144, 1]))
>>> signer = w3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)
>>> signed = signer.signHash(_hash.hex())
>>>
>>> signed.signature
HexBytes('0x805722a36cdc140e5bad965e9511c2479d03a5e1540fb8a4be61390f35d303d5784ba8eeae759b4600e034a9721e7e32549913d0cb28c56aa24bff0ca35f356a1c')
>>>
```

*Lifted functions for testing and included an example call*

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.7; 
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

contract c {
  function get_hash() public pure returns (bytes32) {
    address addr = 0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E;
    uint256 hashes = 1;
    uint256 blockid = 59144;
    uint256 seshid = 1;
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addr, hashes, blockid, seshid));
  }

  function toEthSignedMessageHash(bytes32 hash) public pure returns (bytes32 message) {
    assembly {
      mstore(0x00, "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32")
      mstore(0x1c, get_hash())
      message := keccak256(0x00, 0x3c)
    }
  }

  function verify(bytes memory sig) public pure returns (address) {
    return recover(get_hash(), sig);
  }

  function recover(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) internal pure returns (address signer) {
    if (signature.length == 65) {
      bytes32 r;
      bytes32 s;
      uint8 v;
      assembly {
        r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
        s := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
        v := byte(0, mload(add(signature, 0x60)))
      }
      return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**edit:**

What I think, is that api method is some off chain function returning a signature from a key it has control of, signing the data you pass it. That's the reason you can't recreate it, and the reason it returns that address that isn't yours.

Because it's the address that actually signed the data.

- https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/linea/0xb4c4e1cc619cdabf9572174aa4122d14b0c365e3be378791645f86df575d7651/debugger?trace=0.0.0.0.0
- The result of ec recover in python
  [image]
- The result of ec recover from within the transaction (at the contract)
  [image]

Comment: Please note (did comment within the example) that `keccak(encode_packed())` is the same as `solidity_keccak` and can be imported from `eth_abi` which comes with web3py. `encode` is keccak on the *padded* encoding, so where you may see `keccak256(encode())` in solidity, there you must explicitly use `keccak(encode())` rather than `solidty_keccak` or `keccak(encode_packed())`.