Is it possible to predict the signature(r,s) that will be generated?
look up the transaction (0xfefb2da535e927b85fe68eb81cb2e4a5827c905f78381a01ef2322aa9b0aee8e) where the ERC1820 contract was deployed on Ethereum, you will see the following.
eth.getTransaction("0xfefb2da535e927b85fe68eb81cb2e4a5827c905f78381a01ef2322aa9b0aee8e")

{
  blockHash: "0x1571a4f79960ecbc0bf4ca038c10d155cf6bf0fc61882fe4c3ea076cf999eb3c",
  blockNumber: 7496550,
  from: "0xa990077c3205cbdf861e17fa532eeb069ce9ff96",
  gas: 800000,
  gasPrice: 100000000000,
  hash: "0xfefb2da535e927b85fe68eb81cb2e4a5827c905f78381a01ef2322aa9b0aee8e",
  input: "...too long contract bytescode...",
  nonce: 0,
  r: "0x1820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820",
  s: "0x1820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820",
  to: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  type: "0x0",
  v: "0x1b",
  value: 0
}

The signature data (r,s) of ECDSA is randomly generated. However, the signature data of the transaction seems to be created by a human.
Is it possible to intentionally create signature data like that?
If so, I'd like to see a technique or example of how it could be done.

What is the signature data of the transaction, relative to the signature? The signature is r,s,v concatenated together. Some examples of construction and deconstruction here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162123/solidity-keccak-not-matching-js-keccak256abi-encodepacked/162125#162125 | If better understand the questions can do a direct example.

My question is that the values of r,s in that transaction were created by a human. In EDCSA, r,s are generated as random values. By coincidence, 0x182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820182018201820 could be generated, but it's too unlikely, and I'm wondering how to generate it.

This is using a clever trick that has been around for quite a while. Nick Johnson of ENS wrote an article a while back that should explain it. There is also a brief explanation under "DeploymentMethod" on EIP-1820
It's not the simplest trick to understand, but here is an explanation of how you would do this yourself

Create the raw, unsigned transaction you want to send. Note that raw transactions do not include the address that is sending it, for this example lets say the transaction is just {to: 0x00..00dead, value: 1, nonce: 0}. A simple transaction to 0x00..00dead that sends 1 WEI. The nonce must be 0, the reason for that will become clear later. (Note: The transaction would also include gas information, but for simplicity we can ignore that)

Create the signature for that transaction. Now, normally what you would do is take the private key of the sending account and sign a special hash of the transaction. That's not what we're going to do. Instead we're just gonna pick, well, any old data for the signature. Most people will use clearly non-random data for this, i.e. the 0x1820..1820 values, to show that it is not random.

Remember how I mentioned that raw transactions don't include the address that is sending it? That's because the address is actually obtained by doing some cryptography, essentially allowing you to reverse the signing process to get the sender address using the signature and raw transaction. This is commonly referred to as "ecrecover" if you want to read more specifically on that
So we took this arbitrary signature and raw transaction, did ecrecover to get the signing address...but wait. There was no signing address. Ahh, well it actually doesn't really matter! ecrecover will still work all the same, it will still spit out the address that mathematically "signed" it.

Wait...if it just spits out an address without us knowing it ahead of time, now what? Well that part is pretty simple. Now all we need to do is send some ETH to the address we reverse engineered to pay for the gas of the transaction (and the 1 WEI we are sending in it), broadcast the "signed" transaction to the network, and wait for it to get included in a block.

You've now sent a transaction from an account that you don't know the private key to, but why? The most common reason to do this is so that you could provably generate contracts with the same address across networks. This works because we have essentially generated an account with no private key that can only ever be used to send 1 specific transaction. This is also why it's important that the nonce be 0, since you will *never * be able to send more than the initial transaction from this account, as you don't know its private key



Great trick. Thank you for clarifying.

wow.. it is Great trick ..! and great explanation!! This has been a great help!
